# Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

у меня есть такой HTML:

```
<body>
    
    <div>
        <canvas
            id='game'
            width='600px'
            height='400px'
            style='
                margin: auto;
                margin-top: 40px;               
                display: block;
                background-color: #252734;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            '
        /></canvas>
        <script src='game.js'></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

И такой JS:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

И ошибка:

[image: canvas.getContext is not a function]

Comment: const canvas = document.getElementById("wornet"); Не тот id...

Answer (score 2):

У вас поиск идет по селектору `#game`, а `canvas` имеет идентификатор `#wornet`, поэтому вы пытаетесь получить функцию, которой нет у данного элемента.

Еще бывает так, что на странице может не быть элемента с id  в момент выполнения `document.getElementById("SELECTOR");`. Избавиться от такой ошибки можно будет путём отрисовки страницы целиком и  только потом искать элемент. Для ожидания загрузки страницы можно использовать слушателя на событие `load`

```
window.addEventListener('load', YOUR_CALLBACK);
```

---

**UPD** Если у вас два одинаковых `id`, тогда берётся первый попавшийся и это опять же будет `div`, а не `canvas`. Нельзя (сильно не рекомендуется) делать больше одного уникального id на странице

---

Также почините html. Закрывающий `/` у вас стоит в открывающем теге

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id='game' width='600px' height='400px' style='
                margin: auto;
                margin-top: 40px;               
                display: block;
                background-color: #252734;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            '></canvas>
  <script src='game.js'></script>
</div>
```

Comment: нет, у меня везде #wornet, просто для вопроса я подменил на #game

Comment: @АнтонБожич  Дайте реальный html. Если у вас два одинаковых `id`, тогда берётся первый попавшийся и это опять же будет `div`, а не `canvas`. Нельзя (сильно не рекомендуется) делать больше одного уникального id на странице

Comment: согласен. Я убрал ИД у дива. Теперь все норм, но ошибка не пропала

Comment: @АнтонБожич Также почините html. Закрывающий `/` у вас стоит в открывающием теге - добавил в ответ

Comment: @АнтонБожич если ответ помог - можно ткнуть галочку напротив ответа и стрелочку вверх :)